# In included file: unknown type name 'c' in qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbHER.png)  [error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APtR8.png) [error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4KkR.png) [error 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2smif.png)

I added some label to my program and after I added it I got this error, I have no idea what has changed, I'll be very glad if you can help me
This is the mainwindow.h part:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
~MainWindow();

private slots:
void on_label_linkActivated(const QString &link);

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

As I said it happened after I tried to add label to my program, so that is the part with adding label.

This is the main.cpp part:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
//Setting the optimal window size
w.resize(1100,700);
//Making new label
QLabel *label1 = new QLabel;
//Assigning text "Welcome" to the label
label1->setText("Welcome");
//Setting background color and color of the text
label1->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : none; color : white; }");
label1->resize(400,400);
label1->show();
w.show();
return a.exec();
```

}

`mainwindow.h`:
[image: mainwindow.h]

`main.cpp`:
[image: main.cpp]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your [mre] (copy-pasted *as text*) in the question itself.

Comment: What editor or IDE are you using? If you actually *build* the code, do you get the same or a similar error? If you also get an actual build error, please copy-paste it (as text) into your question as well.

Comment: Xcode, yeah I get this error while building, but as I said originally everything worked well. I'll edit my post with the error picture.

Comment: Have you ever opened the `qwidget.h` header file? Could you (by mistake) have pressed the `c` key anywhere (specifically line 333) while the file was opened? Or possible the `Enter` key (on line 332)? What is happening on line 333 of `qwidget.h`? Is there someone else that could have modified the `qwidget.h` file by mistake? Pet? Room-mate? Significant other?

Comment: Thank you so much , I've just checked it and as you said there was "c", probably pressed it by mistake while checking the functions